# Prove that $A$ is closed if and only if $A=\ cl(A)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Prove that $A$ is closed if and only if $A=\ cl(A)$

So this is my attempt for an answer.

Pf-Suppose $A\subseteq X$ is closed.

In the backward direction, the proof is trivial since if $A=\ cl(A)\Rightarrow A$ is closed.

In the forward direction,

Since $\ cl(A)$ is the smallest closed subset that contains $A$ then by definition of the closure of a set, we obtain the trivial answer  $A\subseteq \ cl(A)$.

Since A is closed. let $x\in \ cl(A)$ $\Rightarrow \forall r>0,\space B(x;r)\cap A\neq \emptyset\space $. Now, fix $r>0\space$ so that   $\space B(x;r)\cap A\subseteq A\ \Rightarrow x\in A$ so we obtain we obtain $\ cl(A)\subseteq A$.

So we get $cl(A)=A$

Comment: What is your definition of closed set? What are you allowed to use?

Comment: This is from Conway's "A course in point set topology." A set is closed if the complement is open, typical definition they give on any course in topology or set theory A set is open if for every x you can find a ball of radius r and is contained in the set. An element is in the closure of a set if and only if for every r>0, the intersection of the ball and the set is nonempty

Answer (score 1):

The mistake in your proof is that you don't justify why $B(x;r)\cap A$ contains $x.$

Let $x \in cl(A).$ Suppose $x \notin A.$ Then $x \in A^c.$ Since $A$ is closed, therefore $A^c$ is open. Therefore there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x;r) \subseteq A^c.$ Hence  $B(x;r) \cap A = \emptyset.$ However this contradicts $x \in cl(A).$

Answer (score 0):

Well one direction is trivial, because the closure of a set is by definition a certain type of closed set.

The other direction is nearly as easy because of the type of closed set the closure is.  It's the smallest closed set containing $A$.  But there is no smaller set containing $A$ than $A$ itself.